# Running PySpark statements in AWS SageMaker Studio Lab

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Folks:
Apologies if this is a very basic question. I am trying out SageMaker Studio Lab https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws

After creating a new Notebook, I noticed there are choices of two kernels:

- default:Python
- sagemaker-distribution:Python

However neither of these seem to support PySpark coding.

When I attempt to set up a PySpark session, I get an error about the JAVA_HOME not being set.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("My ML Application") \
    .config("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com") \
    .getOrCreate()


JAVA_HOME is not set
```

Is there any way to code in PySpark using SageMaker Studio Lab ?